# How to format output as a decimal with two decimal places

Tags: awk

I have written this code that is supposed to output data in the format: (STRING) (INT).

```
`grep "<Overall>" hotel_*.dat | sed 's/\.dat:<Overall>/ /' | awk '{sum[$1] += $2; counts[$1]++;} END {for (i in sum) print i, sum[i]/counts[i];}' | sort -nrk2`
```

I am trying to round up the integer to two decimal places but I have trouble figuring it out. The output is in `print i, sum[i]/counts[i];` and I am trying to round `sum[i]/counts[i]`.

Comment: Without some reasonable example input, it's hard to to test any answers we might have.  I suggest you replace that initial `grep` and `sed` (why two separate commands, when a single `sed` will work?) with something that gives a reasonable input to your `awk` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to set `OFMT`, but note that this won't produce a fractional part for values that happen to be integers:

```
$ awk -v OFMT=%.2f \
   '{sum[$1] += $2; counts[$1]++;} END {for (i in sum) print i, sum[i]/counts[i];}' \
   <<END
a 5
a 4
b 8
b 10
c 4
c 4
c 5
END
```

```
a 4.50
b 9
c 4.33
```

A more reliable method is to use `printf` instead of `print`:

```
$ awk \
   -e '{sum[$1] += $2; counts[$1]++;}' \
   -e 'END {for (i in sum) printf "%s %.2f\n", i, sum[i]/counts[i];}' \
   <<END
a 5
a 4
b 8
b 10
c 4
c 4
c 5
END
```

```
a 4.50
b 9.00
c 4.33
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf` and set the precision

```
grep "<Overall>" hotel_*.dat | sed 's/\.dat:<Overall>/ /' |  awk '{sum[$1] += $2; counts[$1]++;} END {for (i in sum) printf "%s %.10g\n",  i, sum[i]/counts[i];}'  | sort -nrk2
```

or `CONVFMT`

```
grep "<Overall>" hotel_*.dat | sed 's/\.dat:<Overall>/ /' |  awk -v CONVFMT=%.10g '{sum[$1] += $2; counts[$1]++;} END {for (i in sum) printf "%s %.10g\n",  i, sum[i]/counts[i];}'  | sort -nrk2
```